# Is there a way to allow paste from the clipboard using Shift-Insert on top of CTRL-V?

Tags: apache-flex, insert, paste, shift

I know that you can use the context menu using a right-mouse-click in a control to choose to cut, copy, paste, etc.  I've also noticed that you can use the windows keyboard shortcuts CTRL-C for Copy and CTRL-V for Paste.

Windows supports native CTRL-Insert (for copy) and SHIFT-Insert (for paste).

However, within Flex, it seems these do not appear to work.  Has anyone been able to either allow these keyboard events?  Any solutions are appreciated.

Comment: What context are you talking about?  They should work within a text area or text input, but that's it.

Comment: Well, CTRL-C and CTRL-V do work within a text area or input, but CTRL-Insert and SHIFT-Insert don't work.  They pretty much perform the same function.  I guess 99% of the population uses CTRL-C and CTRL-V, though.  I'm in the minority.

But you should notice that CTRL-Insert and SHIFT-Insert work in almost all other Windows applications.

Comment: This is a regression issue in Flex it works on older controls, not in spark controls. A bug has been filed. https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=2928015 If you feel it should be corrected, vote for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clipboard class is available starting from Flash Player 10.

Answer (score 1):

Note: The operating system and the web browser will process keyboard events before Adobe Flash Player or AIR. For example, in Microsoft Internet Explorer, pressing Ctrl+W closes the browser window before any contained SWF file dispatches a keyboard event.

You can just do something similar to this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
 layout="absolute" creationComplete="init()">

 <mx:Script>

 <![CDATA[

    private function init():void{

     this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickHandler);

     this.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,keyPressed);

    }

    private function clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {

      stage.focus = this;

    }

    private function keyPressed(evt:KeyboardEvent):void{

       if(evt.ctrlKey && evt.keyCode == 65)

             trace("CTRL A is pressed");

       if(evt.ctrlKey && evt.keyCode == 66)

             trace("CTRL B is pressed");

   }

 ]]>

 </mx:Script>

</mx:Application>
```

Then To write to the operating system clipboard:

```
import flash.desktop.ClipboardFormats;

 var copy:String = "A string to copy to the system clipboard.";
 Clipboard.generalClipboard.clear();
 Clipboard.generalClipboard.setData(ClipboardFormats.TEXT_FORMAT, copy);
```

To read from the operating system clipboard:

```
import flash.desktop.ClipboardFormats;

 var pasteData:String  = Clipboard.generalClipboard.getData(ClipboardFormats.TEXT_FORMAT) as String;
```

Comment: I am using Flex Builder 3 and dont see where I can import flash.desktop.  I've only found the following, but it only lets you paste to the windows clipboard.  I actually haven't tested it, but I'm still trying to find a way to paste into a TextInput.  I already wrote the KeyboardEvent code to grab the Shift-Insert event.  I just don't know how to gain access to the system clipboard.  Maybe I'm missing flash.desktop.* somehow.

import flash.system.System;
System.setClipboard(string);

Comment: It is in AIR Only.

http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/desktop/Clipboard.html